# Open HTML page with href

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML template code like

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Funky HTML Page</title>
<meta name="description" content="Our first page">
<meta name="keywords" content="html tutorial template">
</head>
<body>
Content goes here.
</body>
</html>
```

I want generate a link in my html template who render this code into a new page
For now I have done a function like this

```
function stringToHtml(htmlString: string) {
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
  return doc.body;
}
```

who take html string (my template) as argument.

In my template (where I need to render this link) I interpolate this function

```
function generateLink(myHtmlTemplate: string, text: string){
  const page = stringToHtml(myHtmlTemplate)
  return `<a href="${page}" target="_blank">${text}</a>`
}
```

But I don't know I can I do to open the HTML render after a click on the link